# Threading in selenium webdriver in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium

I am trying to get used to Selenium WebDriver. By that, I am trying to login and do something on my targeted website. In the code, I tried to log in for 10 users. However, as expected, it isn't the best approach. My first concern is how to do it in better way and secondly, how to create threads at once for each user and start simultaneously.

```
# User threads
t1 = threading.Thread(target=user_qsinav_normal, args=("student@foo.com.tr1", "123456", True))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=user_qsinav_normal, args=("student@foo.com.tr2", "123456", True))
t3 = threading.Thread(target=user_qsinav_normal, args=("student@foo.com.tr3", "123456", True))
t4 = threading.Thread(target=user_qsinav_normal, args=("student@foo.com.tr4", "123456", True))
t5 = threading.Thread(target=user_qsinav_normal, args=("student@foo.com.tr5", "123456", True))
t6 = threading.Thread(target=user_qsinav_normal, args=("student@foo.com.tr6", "123456", True))
t7 = threading.Thread(target=user_qsinav_normal, args=("student@foo.com.tr7", "123456", True))
t8 = threading.Thread(target=user_qsinav_normal, args=("student@foo.com.tr8", "123456", True))
t9 = threading.Thread(target=user_qsinav_normal, args=("student@foo.com.tr9", "123456", True))
t10 = threading.Thread(target=user_qsinav_normal, args=("student@foo.com.tr10", "123456", True))

# Starting threads
t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
t4.start()
t5.start()
t6.start()
t7.start()
t8.start()
t9.start()
t10.start()
```

I changed the code as follows:

```
# creating make up users in the function and return it as dict(email,pass)
users = number_of_users(6)

# logging in with users created before.
for user_email, user_passwoard in users.items():
    threading.Thread(target=user_qsinav_normal, args=(user_email, user_passwoard, True)).start()
```

Comment: Do you really have to use Selenium? Requests would be way faster

Comment: I am not really sure. I am not using since I think selenium is the best fit for this purpose. I am asked to use Selenium since after logging in user clicks somewhere moves on, selecting something etc.

Comment: You should try to capture the requests and use the requests lib instead, its way faster and it doesnt need much CPU / RAM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think to test the API, it is better to use `requests` or some other tools. You then can create multiple threads to test the login API easily.

Selenium side, not so nice with threading. If you surely need to test it using Selenium, I advise you do not use Thread. Instead, we should use Remote Testing using Selenium Grid.

You can install the Selenium Grid Docker from here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium

Create a grid (below example is 3 standalone browsers), you can create more ports if you want.

```
$ docker network create grid
$ docker run -d -p 4442-4444:4442-4444 --net grid --name selenium-hub selenium/hub:4.0.0-alpha-7-prerelease-20200921
$ docker run -d --net grid -e SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub -e SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442 -e SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/node-chrome:4.0.0-alpha-7-prerelease-20200921
$ docker run -d --net grid -e SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub -e SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442 -e SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/node-firefox:4.0.0-alpha-7-prerelease-20200921
$ docker run -d --net grid -e SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub -e SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442 -e SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/node-opera:4.0.0-alpha-7-prerelease-20200921
```

Then point your test to the ports:

```
from selenium import webdriver

firefox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    options=firefox_options
)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
driver.quit()
```

You can build a small custom engine with "Thread" to run Selenium test on the hub. The hub will handle the testing for you, and it will respond back to your thread.